Transformer power mismatch in Falstad Circuit Simulator, bug or true to life?
To understand how transformers function better, I created a circuit in Falstad Circuit Simulator. As you can see since the transformer has equal amount of coil windings in both sides, the current and the voltage is equal minus some resistive losses.

Simulation screenshot 1
However, when I tried to turn it into 10x step-up transformer, things got weird. As you can see, instead of expecting the voltage across the secondary to increase tenfold and current to drop tenfold to conserve power, what happens is the secondary stays entirely the same(except a minor increase in voltage), yet the primary starts drawing 10 times the current with the same voltage, hence increasing its power 10 times. The power dissipated across the resistors before the primary is minor in any case, around 467 Watts with the 10x stepped up current, not explaining where the rest of the power(several tens of kilowatts) went to. The power in the secondary is about 7300 Watts.

Simulation screenshot 2
Assuming this is not a bug of the Falstad Circuit Simulator and is true to life, questions are:

Why is the voltage not stepped up, but instead the primary starts drawing so much more current?
What happens to the unaccounted extra power that is neither dissipated across the primary nor the secondary resistors?
What kind of circuit would I need to draw to make it actually behave like a textbook transformer(10x voltage step up, 10x current step down)?


What do you get if you adjust the load resistor to 300 ohm?


Why is the voltage not stepped up, but instead the primary starts
drawing so much more current?

It's all about the coupling factor of 99.9%. This means that the leakage inductance is 0.1% of 4 henries (the primary magnetization inductance). That's 4 mH and, at 50 Hz, that's a reactance of 1.26 Ω.
That leakage impedance/reactance is in series with the primary winding of your transformer and will drop volts as soon as the transformer is feeding any significant load current. And, it does not contribute to coupling magnetic fields to the secondary.
And, what of the load current; you have a 30 Ω secondary load that you expect to apply 10× the primary voltage to i.e. 4000 volts RMS. That's a secondary current of 133.2 amps and, must mean a primary current of 1333 amps.
Ask your self how much voltage will be dropped across the primary leakage reactance when 1333 amps are trying to flow.
When you have that under control (by making the coupling more like 99.9999%) you'll then find that the 0.1 Ω resistors are the new limiting factor to preventing a primary current of 1333 amps.

What happens to the unaccounted extra power that is neither dissipated across the primary nor the secondary resistors?

It's the volt-amp reactive power generated by the leakage inductance.

What kind of circuit would I need to draw to make it actually behave like a textbook transformer(10x voltage step up, 10x current step down)?

Well, a textbook transformer doesn't really mean anything but, if you mean an ideal transformer with non-ideal coupling then my earlier words will help.

Hello, sorry for the late reply.
What I didn't quite get is how it relates to Ohm's Law. For example, I played with primary inductance and coupling coefficient to get something closer to how you would expect a transformer to behave, but as soon as I decreased the resistance in the secondary to 200m Ohms(to match the primary to see how it would work with equal resistance on both sides) but that caused a voltage drop in the secondary immediately as well, no step up again. And this time changing any of the parameters don't help, other than the resistance.

@ArthurMorgan what I suggest you do is this. Raise a new post showing the new circuit and all parasitic components clearly. What you are asking in comments cannot adequately be addressed in comments and remember, this site is for answering questions contained in your main post and additionally, nobody likes goal-posts changing so, raise a new post and leave a message here to remind me to take a look at it. But, as a short attempt, lowering the secondary load to 200 milli ohms is a bizarre thing to do.

And finally, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
